# Best way to connect Loopback and DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, loopbackjs

I'm trying to connect loopback 3 and DynamoDB in Node. I'm new to both but a colleague on the project suggested this connector:  https://github.com/mandarzope/loopback-connector-dynamodb#readme. However this only has a few stars and no instructions that I see. I found another connector on GitHub but it's not even in the NPM registry, also has only a few stars,  and I was recommended against using it

Is this first package the recommended manner to connect the Loopback and DynanoDB, or I'd there a better way?  Any recommendations much appreciated.

Comment: Best way will be to not use any third party connecter and stick to using AWS provided SDK. (from my experience)